# validation fails on submit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation

The code should validate that the input fields dont contain a number and only letters and also both fields arent blank. Currently it works with detecting if they aren't blank but it only detects a number in 'firstname' - I have managed to get one or the other working but never both at the same time. Help!!

Also, If the validation fails the joke shouldn't be returned (the button onclick provides the joke by using the first and last name and sending it to an api to retrieve the joke).

```
   function validateForm() {
        var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
        var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
        var input = document.getElementsByName("firstname" && "lastname");
        if (firstname == "" && lastname == "") {
            alert("Please enter atleast one name");


        }
        else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(firstname || lastname))) {
            alert("'Only alphabets allowed'");

        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="jokeForm" >
            <form name="searchForm" >
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" value={firstname} onChange={(e) => setFN(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" value={lastname} onChange={(e) => setLN(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <button onClick={() => validateForm(newJoke(firstname, lastname))}>click here for a personalised chuckle</button>
            <h3>{joke}</h3>
        </div >

    )
}
```

Comment: Please note that you are using`AND` condition in if statement: `if (firstname == "" && lastname == "")`. Use `||`(OR) condition to check fields are empty or not

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` to add both strings together. And do test with Regex. eg.

```js
var firstname="j";
var lastname="k1";
if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(firstname + lastname))) {
        alert("Only alphabets allowed!");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Im still having the second problem of the form still being passed (the joke being returned) even when validation has failed. Know what to do?

Comment: Thank you. Just tried to implement this in a few ways but struggled to be successful. Could you show me how it works in the code above?

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your first comment. I don't know `reactjs` but you will get idea from https://jsbin.com/damewuhoxu/edit?output